# project folder in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I understand that in an `sbt` project, `sbt` generates a folder called project containing `build.properties` and `plugins.sbt`. Now if I have one project that has multi subprojects, should I have only one folder called `project` in the root project or different folders named project foreach subproject?

Comment: If you use a multi-module project then only one top-level project folder. However, if each folder is its own self-contained sbt project with its own build.sbt then one project folder per folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only one `project` folder. You can read about it at [Multi-project builds](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Multi-project+builds) in sbt documentation.

For example, to the following sbt:

```scala
name := "new_proj"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(util, core)

lazy val util = (project in file("util"))

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
```

You should have the structure:

```
new_proj
  |- build.sbt
  |- project
    |- build.properties
  |- core
    |- src
      |- main
        |- scala
  |- util
    |- src
      |- main
        |- scala
```