# IntelliJ doesn't recognize properly SBT plugin test projects under 'sbt-test'

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

While everything in SBT is correct and work properly, all sub-projects in [sbt-test](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html#step+3%3A+src%2Fsbt-test) are not recognized by IntelliJ. (leading to red hell inside files)

I tried to add them as module from existing source, but it led to an error (plugin version property isn't available from tested plugin project).

If by chance someone has already configured this, could you explain the procedure to follow?

[image: structure]

Comment: First check it working using SBT directly, if yes, the SBT setup in InteliJ is faulty

Comment: I am not sure if your build.sbt is on the right place. Are you creating unit tests? If so, the directory must be `src/test/scala`. Also please post your build.sbt

Comment: Please see [project folder in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65567906/2359227). Can you please share your entire folder structure along with the `build.sbt`?

Comment: cchantep everything works right with SBT. 
Felipe each sub project scoped under sbt-test is a new project testing the plugin and need a build.sbt.
TomerShetah I updated the screen.

Comment: here is a good reference of sbt project with submodules (https://github.com/pbassiner/sbt-multi-project-example). A quick view shows that the `build.sbt` is only one file under the root directory of the project.

Comment: See reference documentation under sbt-test in the question

Comment: Can you create a simple github repo that helps reproducing this issue?